# $\int_0^{\pi}(\sin x)^{({\sin x})^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^\cdots}}} dx=?$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

While playing around with graphs of some  power towers on Desmos, I happened to stumble upon the graph of the function$$y=(\sin x)^{({\sin x})^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^\cdots}}}$$ which can be rewritten as $$y=(\sin x)^y$$ The graph resembles a bunch of spaced-out distorted sinusoids, and Desmos even says it contains too fine details to be graphed perfectly, especially around $x=n\pi$. I don't think the function should be defined for these points as the $y$ value is ambiguous ($y=0^y$), but it does appear to approach $0$. Here is the graph:

[image]

Is there a way to calculate the area under this graph by hand?

Comment: Serious question: do you expect there should be a reason this is likely?

Comment: Another serious question:  Why do any of this "by hand"?

Comment: I'm just curious about the value honestly, but hopefully the area involves some nice constants like $\pi$? No?

Comment: @Tavish life is full of disappointment

Comment: Before you start playing with power towers, you have to know the domain for which they converge: $[(1/e)^e,e^{(1/e)}]$. $\sin(x)$ lies in $[-1,1]$ so for values less than $(1/e)^e$ the tower will be a 2-cycle, so the integral is meaningless. Better if it had bounds like those for the power tower, in which case it would be $\int_{(1/e)^e}^{1} \frac{W(-\log(\sin(x))}{-\log(\sin(x))}dx$, which i don't believe has a nice closed form. If you want the value of that, plug the above expression into Wolfram or Maple.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis That is sad. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Tavish: No problem.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28Pi-2*arcsin%28y%5E%281%2Fy%29%29%2Cy+%3D+0+..+1%29%29) gives 
$\int_0^1(\pi-2\arcsin(y^{1/y}))\, dy\approx 2.32078$.